# Using Angular Material Button by itself in a Stackblitz?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I use Angular Material all the time on Stackblitz, and usually I import a kitchen sink module, and everything just works.

Now I'm trying to just import the Angular Material Button Module, and I get the error:

```
Error in src/app/app.component.ts (8:14)
Unable to import component MatButton.
The symbol is not exported from /turbo_modules/@angular/material@13.3.5/button/button-module.d.ts (module '@angular/material/button/button-module').
```

This is the Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wxvebj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing `MatButtonModule` from `@angular/material/button/button-module` when you should import it from `@angular/material/button`